# Calling Procedure in 1 line

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, sqlplus

I have a question about calling a procedure in Oracle. 
This is what I have and this works fine in SQLPlus.

```
VARIABLE resultSet REFCURSOR;
 BEGIN 
  CALL_TEST('10DD', :resultSet);
 END;
 /
```

But, the code below doesn't work because it gives me the explanation of the variable instead of saying "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed."

```
VARIABLE resultSet REFCURSOR; BEGIN HUGHES_ARIAL.DUNNING_TEST('1D10', :resultSet); END; /
```

The issue is I need to press enter after every ; (semicolon). Is there a way to make my statement above to work with just 1 line without having to press enter?

I am using an email campaign enterprise software, but it doesn't allow me to do what I can do in SQLPlus.

Comment: `/` has to start on a new line; the rest can be compressed to one line.

Answer (score 1):

All `SQL*Plus` commands should be within one line. When clubbing different commands, it has to be in multiple lines.

**Example:**

```
SQL> variable test NUMBER;set linesize 0;
Usage: VAR[IABLE] [ <variable> [ NUMBER | CHAR | CHAR (n [CHAR|BYTE]) |
                    VARCHAR2 (n [CHAR|BYTE]) | NCHAR | NCHAR (n) |
                    NVARCHAR2 (n) | CLOB | NCLOB | REFCURSOR |
                    BINARY_FLOAT | BINARY_DOUBLE ] ]
```

---

Your Procedure can be invoked this way, using `EXEC`.

```
VARIABLE resultSet REFCURSOR;

EXEC CALL_TEST('10DD', :resultSet);
```

OR

```
VARIABLE resultSet REFCURSOR;

BEGIN CALL_TEST('10DD', :resultSet); END;
/
```

Your entire `PL/SQL` block may be in one line, where-as when attempted to execute, you have to explicitly specify the `'/'` as a new line!

---

If you are concern in running in multiple lines,

Put it in a file and run as Script.

```
SQL> !cat my_script.sql
VARIABLE resultSet REFCURSOR;
 BEGIN
  CALL_TEST('10DD', :resultSet);
 END;
 /

SQL> start my_script.sql
```

Comment: hi Maheswaran,thank you for your response. unfortunately, the software that I am using doesn't support multiple lines and I cannot put it in a file and run as script.

Comment: Oh, but `VARIABLE` is `SQL*Plus` only command to be used! Why not define a `refcursor` inside your `PL/SQL` ?